Настройка андроид эмулятора
Как настроить андроид эмулятор так, чтобы телеграм считал это как реальное устройство?
На данный момент телеграм видит что это эмулятор и ограничивает права.
Использую эту библиотеку https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android

Никак. Потому что это эмулятор.
